# Fix Filename that was changed to ASCII from UTF8

Tags: utf-8, iso-8859-1, mojibake

I recently downloaded a pack of videos that should have Japanese characters as their file names. Instead who ever uploaded them botched the formatting.

Instead of Kana, Hiragana, and Kanji I get;

002òÅü¢âyâbâeâBâôâO(âuâïâ}).mp4

I was wondering if there was a way to fix this short of asking for another upload?

I tried to put the names into a Text file and then hex edit that file to change it's encoding, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) library for Python as an aid to guess at the encoding.

```
>>> import chardet
>>> s='002òÅü¢âyâbâeâBâôâO(âuâïâ}).mp4'
>>> chardet.detect(s.encode('l1'))
{'encoding': 'ISO-8859-5', 'confidence': 0.536359806931924, 'language': 'Russian'}
>>> chardet.detect(s.encode('cp437'))
{'encoding': 'SHIFT_JIS', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': 'Japanese'}
>>> chardet.detect(s.encode('cp850'))
{'encoding': 'SHIFT_JIS', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': 'Japanese'}
```

Probably not ISO-8859-1, more likely IBM 437 or 850.

```
>>> s.encode('cp850').decode('sjis')
'002撫⊃ペッティング(ブルマ).mp4'
>>> s.encode('cp437').decode('sjis')
'002撫○ペッティング(ブルマ).mp4'
```

Could be either one of these, but I can't read them.

Comment: I've never used Python before. I did the import chardet, did the variable assignment. I get an error on chardet (line 3) that states "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)" What did I do wrong?

Comment: Switch to Python 3.

Comment: Ah, I was using python on the console. It's python3. Thanks, now to get this into function form and make a program I can run on those files to rename them. Thanks for the information.

Comment: For the record, cp437 was the correct code page, the other one bugged out 75% of the time.

Comment: @JoshLee Hi, I tried to follow this answer but still get error when tried to convert this following string into utf8 (not sure if it shiftjis or what) "âWâââPâbâgâCâëâXâg". However I did know the expected string should be "ジャケットイラスト".